# jQuery add count to class

Tags: jquery, count

I've been stairing, trying and tweaking this code for over 2hrs now and I'm still no closer to figuring it out.

I'm trying to do the following,

If div has class **.item1**, **.item2**, **.item3** add css style to each, But I need the .item(number) to get count automatically as further in my script I have divs that are automatically created with .item(number) classes.

I just need the '.single-attendee-wrapper' to have '.item + (i+1)' aswell but I cant get this to work.

Latest amends -

```
/* Inline validation */
.on( 'blur change', '.input-text', function() {
    $(".single-attendee-wrapper").each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this);
        var validated = true;

        if ( $(".cart > .item" + (i+1)) ) {
            if ( $this.val() == '' ) {
                $(".item" + (i+1) + " .count").css('background','#ED616A');
                $(".item" + (i+1) + " .count").css('color','#fff');
                validated = false;
            }
        }
        if ( validated ) {
                $(".item" + (i+1) + " .count").css('background','#D1D3D4');
                $(".item" + (i+1) + " .count").css('color','#808285');
        }

    });
} )
```

Here is my snippet so far,

```
.on( 'blur change', '.input-text', function() {
    var count = 0;


    $(".single-attendee-wrapper .input-text").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var validated = true;
        count++;

        if ( $(this) ) {
            if ( $this.val() == '' ) {
                $('.item'+ count + ' .count').css('background','#ED616A');
                $('.item'+ count + ' .count').css('color','#fff');
                validated = false;
            }
        }
        if ( validated ) {
                $('.item'+ count + ' .count').css('background','#D1D3D4');
                $('.item'+ count + ' .count').css('color','#808285');
        }

    });
} )
```

Further into my script, this works perfect.

```
$(".single-attendee-wrapper").each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("item" + (i+1));
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="single-attendee-wrapper item1">
<div class=" product-addon product-addon-one-attendee" style="display: block;">
<div class="count" style="">1</div>
</div>
<div class="single-attendee-wrapper item2">
<div class=" product-addon product-addon-two-attendees" style="display: block;">
<div class="count" style="">2</div>
</div>
<div class="single-attendee-wrapper item3">
<div class=" product-addon product-addon-three-attendees" style="display: block;">
<div class="count" style="">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML for me to work with?  I'm having trouble understanding exactly what your issue is.

Comment: I've successfully added '.item(number)' to '.single-attendee-wrapper' and now I'm wanting to make the script find all '.item(numbers)' and add the css to it. I can do it the long way by typing in all the .item classes indervidually but to save time i though finding an awser to fix.

Comment: Thats great, but I still can't really help you without any HTML to analyze your code against.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all classes starting with `item{*}`, you can use the "*[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)"*:

```
$("div[class^='item']")
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/3ksDp/)

Comment: This would work if I was targeting all items but I want to add style to the div with the same item(number).

Comment: Hm, then I still don't get you. Can you please rephrase your problem?

Comment: I have 12 divs each with there own class e.g .item1, .item6, .item12 I'm wanting to add css style to the individual div using the class number e.g div has .item8 the style would need to be added to .item8, I hope this helps you understand my problem.

Comment: So is your problem actually that `$('.item'+ count + ' .count')` fails?

Comment: Yeah, Looks like the count isn't picking up the correct number

Comment: @AdamWadsworth Did you leave the part out in your example. Because there's not a single element with the class `.input-text` in any `single-attendee-wrapper`.